# Insert keypress in input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, keypress

Hi i have  a problem  with  insert value in  input

You might ask why I did put keypress input field with JS?
I have the compiled program emscripten and it has driver input that intercepts all keypress, keydown, keyup and returns false for other element on page.
That blocks all input fields on page.
I have no way to fix this in the emscripten program, and I decided to fix it by jQuery on html side

```js
   jQuery(function() {
        var $input = jQuery("#search-area228");
        $input
            .attr("tabindex", "0")
            .mousedown(function(e){ jQuery(this).focus(); return false; })
             .keypress(function(e){
     var data = jQuery(this).val
    var text = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.charCode)
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    jQuery(this).val(text[i])
    return false; });
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-area228">
```

This will unlock the input field, but the problem is that allows you to write only one character and when you click on the following replaces it!
Please, help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the new text to the pre-existing text in that field which you already defined (in a wrong way) as `data` and didn't use it

when you call the method `val` of an input you should use it with braces `jQuery(this).val()` NOT `jQuery(this).val` because this is a function method of `jQuery` not a variable.

```js
jQuery(function() {
        var $input = jQuery("#search-area228");
        $input
            .attr("tabindex", "0")
            .mousedown(function(e){ jQuery(this).focus(); return false; })
             .keypress(function(e){
     var data = jQuery(this).val();
    var text = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.charCode)
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    jQuery(this).val(data + text[i])//<<< here
    return false; });
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-area228">
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
The solution was quite simple.
But the way, the event works only on keydown and keyup.
But there is one problem, does not work backspace.
Any ideas how to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code had little mistake.
You were setting the value of the input to the current key instead of appending it to the current value of the input.

```
jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val() + text[i]);
```

This is the fixed version:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var $input = jQuery("#search-area228");
    $input.attr("tabindex", "0")
        .mousedown(function (e) {
        jQuery(this).focus();
        return false;
    })
        .keypress(function (e) {
        var data = jQuery(this).val
        var text = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.charCode)
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val() + text[i]);
        return false;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-area228">
```